# MATLAB: search for elements in an array matching multidimensional condition

Tags: arrays, matlab, conditional-statements

I have a column vector (V1) of real numbers like:

```
123.2100
125.1290
...
954.2190
```

If I add, let's say, a number 1 to each row in this vector, I will get (V2):

```
124.2100
126.1290
...
955.2190
```

I need to find out how many elements from V2 are inside some error-window created from V1. For example the error-window = 0.1 (but in my case every element in V1 has it's own error window):

```
123.1100 123.3100
125.0290 125.2290
...
954.1190 954.3190
```

I can create some code like this:

```
% x - my vector
% ppm - a variable responsible for error-window
window = [(1-(ppm/1000000))*x, (1+(ppm/1000000))*x]; % - error-window
mdiff = 1:0.001:20; % the numbers I will iteratively add to x 
                    % (like the number 1 in the example)
cdiff = zeros(length(mdiff),1); % a vector that will contain counts of elements
                                % corresponding to different mdiff temp = 0;

for i = 1:length(mdiff)
    for j = 1:size(window,1)
        xx = x + mdiff(i);
        indxx = find( xx => window(j,1) & xx <= window(j,2) );
        if any(indxx)
            temp = temp + length(indxx); %edited
        end
    end
    cdiff(i) = temp;
    temp = 0;
end
```

So, at the end cdiff will contain all the counts corresponding to mdiff. The only thing, I would like to make the code faster. Or is there a way to avoid using the second loop (with j)? I mean to directly use a multidimensional condition.

**EDIT**

I decided to simpify the code like this (thanking to the feedback I got here):

```
% x - my vector
% ppm - a variable responsible for error-window
window = [(1-(ppm/1000000))*x, (1+(ppm/1000000))*x]; % - error-window
mdiff = 1:0.001:20; % the numbers I will iteratively add to x 
                    % (like the number 1 in the example)
cdiff = zeros(length(mdiff),1); % a vector that will contain counts of elements
                                % corresponding to different mdiff temp = 0;

for i = 1:length(mdiff)
    xx = x + mdiff(i);
    cdiff(i) = sum(sum(bsxfun(@and,bsxfun(@ge,xx,window(:,1)'),bsxfun(@le,xx,window(:,2)'))));
end
```

In this case the code works faster and seems properly

Comment: I believe you can use something like a binary search, to avoid havig to do all n² iterations. First sort V1, then for each V2, compare to the middle term of V1, and see if it's higher or lower than it. If it's lower, you eliminate the need to check the upper half of V1. And go on until you find a match, or until you run out of candidates

Comment: Some small comments: you don't need to use `find`, you can directly do `if any(xx <= ... & xx >= ...)`. Next, move `xx = ...` before the second for-loop, since it doesn't change as a function of `j`. Your bigger problem is that your algorithm takes `O(n * m^2)` time, where `n = length(mdiff)` and `m = length(x)`.

Comment: @Kirill Make sure the **EDIT** code produces matching values as compared against your original code.

Comment: @Divakar, Yes, it produces. The only thing I have to change in my original version is not to use `temp = temp + 1` but `temp = temp + length(indxx)`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Kirill I just did a quick check with some random values and the values didn't match between your original and modified ones. I would take your word for it anyway.

Comment: @Divakar There's one difference. As I said instead of adding 1 to temp I have to add the whole length of the indxx

Comment: @Kirill You are doing summations on two levels with that modified method. I think that is different from checking to be inside the `window`. Why not use a different name like `cdiff1`for the modified method and compare against `cdiff`?

Comment: @Divakar Sorry, I don't understand exactly the question. When I compare the first and the second versions of the code, I get the same result. Probably because I use quite a small window.

Comment: @Kirill Yes, try a bigger data.

Comment: @Divakar My data consists of 8000-10000 values. I checked only for `mdiff = 1:0.1:2` and everything matched (My work computer is much faster than home one, I can't compare it for bigger ranges here).

Answer (score 0):

Think this might work for you -

```
%%// Input data
V1 = 52+rand(4,1)

V2 = V1+1;
t= 0.1;

low_bd = any(abs(bsxfun(@minus,V2,[V1-t]'))<t,2); %%//'
up_bd = any(abs(bsxfun(@minus,V2,[V1+t]'))<t,2); %%//'
count = nnz( low_bd | up_bd )
```

One could also write it as -

```
diff_map = abs(bsxfun(@minus,[V1-t V1+t],permute(V2,[3 2 1])));
count = nnz(any(any(diff_map<t,2),1))
```

**Edit 1:**

```
low_bd = any(abs(bsxfun(@minus,V2,window(:,1)'))<t,2); %%//'
up_bd = any(abs(bsxfun(@minus,V2,window(:,2)'))<t,2); %%//'
count = nnz( low_bd | up_bd )
```

**Edit 2: Vectorized form for the edited code**

```
t1 = bsxfun(@plus,x,mdiff);
d1 = bsxfun(@ge,t1,permute(window(:,1),[3 2 1]));
d2 = bsxfun(@le,t1,permute(window(:,2),[3 2 1]));
t2 = d1.*d2;
cdiff_vect = max(sum(t2,3),[],1)';
```

Comment: in my case the error term 't' changes as a function of value in V1:                         
**window = [(1-(ppm/1000000))*x, (1+(ppm/1000000))*x]**

Comment: @Kirill So can I assume `t` of the same length as `V1`?

Comment: every element in V1 has it's own error range: **window = [(1-(ppm/1000000))*x, (1+(ppm/1000000))*x]**. In this case I present error window. If something goes inside these windows, I have to count it.

Comment: Divakar, yes that's right. Sorry I wasn't specific in my question

Comment: @Kirill Check out **Edit 1**.

Comment: @Divakar: I don't quite understand the reason for using `bsxfun`(@minus, ...)` with its cryptic syntax as opposed to just `-`?

Comment: Thanks a lot with some ideas. I decided to use:  `count = sum(sum(bsxfun(@and,bsxfun(@ge,a,window(:,1)'),bsxfun(@le,a,window(:,2)'))))`. And seems it works faster.

Comment: @Kirill I was almost finishing up on this and received your comment. Check out **Edit 2** for no-loop-at-all version.

Comment: @mbschenkel You are right `bsxfun` is redundant there and Edit 2 might work for OP, so most probably I would remove Edit 1 anyway.

Comment: @Kirill yes that's one negative thing about using `bsxfun` that it is memory intensive. So, I guess stick to your **EDIT** code.

Answer (score 0):

```
add = 1; %// how much to add
error = .1; %// maximum allowed error

V2 = V1 + add; %// build V2   
ind = sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus, V1(:).', V2(:)))<error)>1; %'// index of elements
%// of V1 satisfying the maximum error condition. ">1" is used to because each 
%// element is at least equal to itself
count = nnz(ind);
```

Comment: For checking to be in that window, aren't you supposed to check for the case of `V1 - add` too?

Comment: What I do is check if abs(V1-V2)<error (all combinations, `bsxfun`-wise). I think that's enough, isn't it?

Comment: @LuisMendo every element in V1 has it's own error term. In this case t will have the same dimension as V1. That's the case I want to check if some elements in V2 fall inside any windows created from V1.